# Adding valid crumb in HTTP POST header, and still getting 403 error

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to trigger a Jenkins build remotely, thorugh an HTTP POST request.
Because Jenkins Security is using CSRF protection, I need to add a valid crumb.
I'm using "Jenkins-server-url/crumbIssuer/api/xml" to get the crumb, and adding it with the correct header field "Jenkins-Crumb".

A few days ago - it worked, and nothing changed since then (not my code); only now, even though I'm adding a valid crumb (I checked - it hasn't changed) I'm still geting a 403 error.

If anyone ran into the same problem and can help, it'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a plugin? Is your remotely build related to git? Is your Jenkins updated?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay - I was sure I'd get an email if anyone answered, and so haven't checked until now. 
The problem worked itself out after a couple of hours - maybe it was a problem in my workplace's Jenkins server, or in the agent (which I had no access to).
Anyway, thank you very much for the reply!